# Session Timeout .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, timeout

I searched but I dont`t find any specific answer for this question.
How I can get value in server how much time left, before session expires?
My session settings:

//timeout for example 10 min.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms name=".ASPXAUTH_External" loginUrl="Authentication/Unauthorized.aspx" protection="All" timeout="10" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Pages/home.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10">
</sessionState>
```

I get initial value (it will get 10*60 = 600 seconds):

```
SessionStateSection sessionSection = (SessionStateSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
countdown.Text = sessionSection.Timeout.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

But when session time left less then half and user do some action. I get initial value 600, but it is not equal for left session time, because "slidingExpiration" **add some time** (I don`t know how much), but not resets session left time to starting 10 min point.

**How can I get remaining session time until expiration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that time  of session expiration I can get like so:

```
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = this.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    double leftSeconds = (authTicket.Expiration - dateNow).TotalSeconds;
    // Control in MasterPage, where I setting value ant then taking for JavaSript to CountDown message
    countdown.Text = leftSeconds > 0 ? leftSeconds.ToString() : "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Drasius approach I coded a VB solution as follows.

In global.asa on Session_Start I have --

```
    Session("sessStart") = DateTime.Now
    Session("TO") = Session.Timeout
```

In page masterfile I have --

```
    Dim timemsg As String = ""
    Dim sstrt As DateTime = Session("sessStart")
    timemsg = "Strt=" & sstrt.ToShortTimeString() & " TO=" & Session("TO") & "<br />"
    Dim datenow = DateTime.Now
    Dim cusrn = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    If cusrn <> "" Then
        Dim authcookie As System.Web.HttpCookie
        authcookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
        Dim authTicket As System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authcookie.Value)
        Dim leftminutes = (authTicket.Expiration - datenow).TotalMinutes
        timemsg &= "Remain: "
        If leftminutes > 0 Then
            timemsg &= leftminutes.ToString("F1") & " mins"
        Else
            timemsg &= "0 mins"
        End If
    End If
    lblShowTime.Text = timemsg
```

This works after a fashion -- when I refresh page I get a reduced time to timeout.  However, the initial time remaining always shows 30 minutes, even though I have web.config setting as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

So I'm not so certain that this approach is giving a timeout that is really synced with the actual session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are server side, it is reset (on any postback), so if you had 10 minutes, it is 10 minutes.  Clientside you can set a timer after the last trip to server, so for example you can set an 8 minute timer and then warn that session expires in 2 minutes...Of course you would want to display the actual time left, not a static message.

Look at the setTimeout method.  [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) has info on some javascript timing methods you might use.

Comment: This. Not solves problem (sliding expiration, doen`t set session expiration to starting point (10 min.) it add`s "some time".)... But when session time left less than half and user do some action. I get value 600 seconds, but it is not equal for left session time, because "slidingExpiration" add some time (I don`t know how much), but not resets session left time to starting 10 min point.